# Can Testcafe fire the event listener of an <input type=number> in my project?

Tags: addeventlistener, testcafe

My project code:

```
html:
<input id="min-days" type="number" onchange="javascript=onRefresh();" oninput="validity.valid||(value='');" placeholder="0 days" min="0" max="99999" />

JavaScript:
var durationInput = document.getElementById("min-days");
durationInput.addEventListener("keydown", function (event) {
    if (event.code == "ArrowUp") {
        durationInput.value = parseInt(durationInput.value || 0) + 364;
    } …
});
```

I'd like my Testcafe test function to enter an `ArrowUp` to the `input` that the event listener catches.

While the project works, I've been unable to get Testcafe to trigger the event handler. I started with `pressKey('up')` and the following. None has worked.

```
#1
test('Date up arrow increments by 365 from 0 on up arrow', 
    async t => {

        await t.eval(() => {
            const input = document.querySelector('#min-days');
            const event = new KeyboardEvent('keydown', { key: 'ArrowUp' });
            input.dispatchEvent(event);
        });

        await t.expect(Selector('#min-days').value).eql('365');
    });
```

```
#2
test('Date up arrow increments by 365 from 0 on up arrow',
    async t => {
        const minDays = Selector('#min-days');
        const getInputNode = ClientFunction(() =>
            document.querySelector('#min-days'));

        await t.eval(() => {
            const input = document.querySelector('#min-days');
            const event = new KeyboardEvent('keyup', { key: 'ArrowUp' });
            input.dispatchEvent(event);
        });
        await t.expect(minDays.value).eql('365');
    });
```

Running `testcafe` asserts:

```
 1) AssertionError: expected '' to deeply equal '365'
      
      + expected - actual
      
      -''
      +365
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `event.code` property is difficult to implement. Please read the information outlined here: https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/3146#issuecomment-444070308

As a workaround, you can use the following approach:

```
await t.dispatchEvent('#min-days', 'keydown', { code: 'ArrowUp' })
```

Comment: thank you! the code worked which is cracking after trying for many hours to find a solution and each of those was more verbose.